# Merge content in a list into a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text, mergesort

In text.txt is:

```
Tommy 1200
Sally 1500
Ricky 2030
Tommy 3200
Sally 2900
Tommy 2190
Tommy 3460
```

I want to merge the content into a dictionary so the result will be like:

```
{'Tommy':[1200,3200,2190,3460],
 'Sally':[1500,2900],
 'Ricky':[2030]}
```

Here is my code so far:

```
dic = {}
name_score = []
with open('text.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip().split(' ')
    name_score.append([line[0],line[1]])
print(name_score)
```

Output:

```
[['Tommy', '1200'], ['Sally', '1500'], ['Ricky', '2030'], ['Tommy', '3200'], ['Sally', '2900'], ['Tommy', '2190'], ['Tommy', '3460']]
```

I've tried further, but things get too confusing for me. Can I get some help?

Comment: Where are 'Jack' and all the 'G*' values coming from in your text.txt?

Comment: How did you get `'G2','G5'..` those are not even present the `.txt` file you showed the question

Comment: Opps! Let me change that!

Comment: @Ch3steR Sorry, I got mixed up.

Comment: You can use `defaultdict` here. `new=defaultdict(list)` now iterate in the same way you did but `for line in lines: k,v= line.strip().split(); new[k].append(v)` should do it

Comment: Try this https://repl.it/repls/TrivialEcstaticFiles much more pythonic way and less number of lines and space than accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through your ns list. For each entry, check if the first value is not already a key in dic. If it isn't, add an empty list to dic under that key. Then, append the second value in the entry to that list in dic.

```
for l in ns:
    if l[0] not in dic:
        dic[l[0]] = []
    dic[l[0]].append(l[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use for `defaultdict` as @Ch3steR notes in the comments (+1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

name_score = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, score = line.strip().split()
        name_score[name].append(score)

print(name_score)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Tommy': ['1200', '3200', '2190', '3460'], 'Sally': ['1500', '2900'], 'Ricky': ['2030']})
>
```

A `defaultdict` can be used just like a dictionary.  If the `defaultdict(<class 'list'>` stuff bothers you in the output, you can call `dict` on the `defaultdict`:

```
 print(dict(name_score))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
{'Tommy': ['1200', '3200', '2190', '3460'], 'Sally': ['1500', '2900'], 'Ricky': ['2030']}
>
```

To get back a generic `dict`.  But the Pythonic thing to do is just work with the `defaultdict` and don't be bothered by the way it prints.

There are tricks to do roughly the same thing with a generic `dict`, e.g. using `setdefault()` but `defaultdict` is a clear, and a well understood way to go about this.  And you can do wild things with it, like `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))` -- a dictionary of automatically created dictionaries of integers!

```
>>> x = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> x['squirrel']['nuts_found'] += 1
>>> x
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10c285b80>, {'squirrel': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'nuts_found': 1})})
>>>
```